# Twilio Classic Functions, How do you work with Tags and SMS?

Tags: binding, notifications, tags, twilio, sms

Twilio function Problem: Tags are not working as expected.

I'm trying to create unique SMS subscription lists for users who SMS 'keyword1','keyword2','keyword3',etc to my number.

I'm doing this by intercepting the 'incoming message' events via a classic function.

I want to poll the keywords then assign tags to the users as I subscribe them to a list.

Then when I broadcast SMS I want to be able to send to only those users who are tagged with my keyword.

For example to capture the keyword 'test' and assign the tag 'test' to a user, I'm using the code below.

And then to send messages to all users with the tag 'test' I'm using a "sendtest" command.

I can broadcast to 'all' tags and it will work fine, but if I want to only send to users with tags ['test'], then there are no errors reported and the system tells me it was successful, but no subscribers will receive any messages.

I'm wondering if I have some problem in the way I am trying to define the tags? It looks like the data format is supposed to be a STRING[] array of some kind, I'm guessing ['test','two','three']. (If I can confirm this is right). But I notice as per the working examples provided by twilio if I set the notification arguments to a string IE: `tags: 'all',` then this syntax works to broadcast to all tags. Anything else though, will not work at all.

is there some trick to getting tags to work, or do they not work at all when trying to filter notifications via the classic function interface?

```
class TestCommand extends Command {
  run(callback) {
    // Create a new SMS Notify binding for this user's phone number
    //and try to tag the user with keyword 'test'
    notify.bindings.create({
      identity: this.fromNumber,
      bindingType: 'sms',
      address: this.fromNumber,
      tags: ['test']
    }).then((response) => {
      callback(null, 'test Message success')
    }).catch(err => {
      callback(err, 'test message fail')
    })
  }
}

class BroadcastTestCommand extends Command {
  run(callback) {
    // Check if sender is in list of admins, stored in the system environment
    // as a comma-separated string
    if (adminNumbers.indexOf(this.fromNumber) < 0) {
      return callback(null, 'broadcast Not Authorized')
    }

    // Create a new SMS Notify binding for this user's phone number
    //only notify users who are tagged with 'test'
    notify.notifications.create({
      tag: ['test'],
      body: this.commandText
    }).then((response) => {
      callback(null, 'broadcast test Success')
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      callback(err, 'broadcast test Fail')
    })
  }
}

// Handle incoming SMS commands ####################
exports.handler = (context, event, callback) => {
  // Get command text from incoming SMS body
  let cmd = event.Body || ''
  cmd = cmd.trim().split(' ')[0].toLowerCase()

  // Default to help command
  let cmdInstance = new HelpCommand(event, context)

  // Choose other commands as appropriate
  switch(cmd) {
    case 'test': cmdInstance = new TestCommand(event, context); break;
    case 'sendtest': cmdInstance = new BroadcastTestCommand(event, context); break;

  }

  // Execute command
  cmdInstance.run((err, message) => {
    let twiml = new twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse()
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      message = 'There was a problem with your request. Try again!'
    }
    twiml.message(message)
    callback(null, twiml)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay for anyone else pulling their hair out on this one..
The Twilio docs here on bindings will throw you off
https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/binding-resource

Because the argument is NOT 'tags' it's 'tag'

This works ...

```
class TestCommand extends Command {
  run(callback) {
    // Create a new SMS Notify binding for this user's phone number
    //and try to tag the user with keyword 'test'
    notify.bindings.create({
      identity: this.fromNumber,
      bindingType: 'sms',
      address: this.fromNumber,
      tag: ['test']
    }).then((response) => {
      callback(null, 'test Message success')
    }).catch(err => {
      callback(err, 'test message fail')
    })
  }
}
```